# Issue in installing mongodb module with npm

Tags: node.js, mongodb

*PS: I am a beginer with nodejs and mongodb. Infact this is my day 1 with nodejs and mongodb and I am following the basic video series from [tutsplus](https://tutsplus.com/course/introduction-to-node-js/)*

I am getting error while installing mongodb module.. (Mac OX Lion, Xcode latest installed, MongoDB shell version: 2.4.3(installed via homebrew), npm -v1.2.15, node -v0.10.2)

> kerberos@0.0.2 install /Users/mohit/projects/nodejs/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
>
> bson@0.1.8 install /Users/mohit/projects/nodejs/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

I am installing via

```
  npm install mongodb
```

I tried installing

```
 npm install -g node-gyp.
```

Still nothing. Any suggestions??

Comment: I had the same problem. Those status messages are very confusing and should not be shown.

Comment: In here node-gyp is waiting to load the node.js source package unless already cached. This can take pretty long on slow network especially when both kerberos and bson build are doing the same thing..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those aren't actually errors. Did you try continuing with the tutorial?

Comment: Yes. It worked.. So dumb I am.. Thanks a lot. But in tutorial the terminal access came back. Thats why I thought its actually a bug